# PHP json_encode to C# Object unable to convert

Tags: c#, php, json, rest

I have this array of objects that contains some strings and an array of strings that I want to return from my server:

> "[{"original_file_name":"Plain_HAIR.pdf","encrypted_file_name":"UTTSJG13V1EC46J.pdf","is_successful":true,"message":"","email":"[\"testuser@gmail.com\"]","doctype":"HAIR"}]"

On my local app, I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class FileUploadResultViewModel
{
    public string original_file_name { get; set; }
    public string encrypted_file_name { get; set; }
    public string is_successful { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string doctype { get; set; }
}

if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileUploadResultViewModel>>(res.Content);
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

The issue is that when it comes back to the local app, I get an error saying :

> {"Error converting value
> "[{"original_file_name":"Plain_HAIR.pdf","encrypted_file_name":"UTTSJG13V1EC46J.pdf","is_successful":true,"message":"","email":"["testuser@gmail.com"]","doctype":"HAIR"}]"
> to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Uploader.ViewModels.FileUploadResultViewModel]'.
> Path '', line 1, position 1521."}

Am I converting it wrongly or are there some steps missing?

EDIT:

This is how I define the object on the server:

```
$object = (object) [
    'original_file_name' => $item["original_file_name"],
    'encrypted_file_name' => $item["file_name"],
    'is_successful' => true,
    'message' => '',
    'email' => NULL,
    'doctype' => $item["doctype"]
];
array_push($myArray, $object);
$this->response(json_encode($myArray));
```

EDIT 2: Showing the method to retrieve the json result

```
public FileUploadResultViewModel Upload(List<FileUploadViewModel> sdvm)
{
    var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sdvm);
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    var link = url;
    var username = username;
    var password = password;
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri(link);
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddJsonBody(sdvm);
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    var res = client.Execute(request);
    if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileUploadResultViewModel>(res.Content);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see one error: `"is_successful":true` is a bool, not a string

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with PHP. The function `json_encode()` just creates standard stringified json, so the fact that it comes from PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I understand. I was just wondering if there was any issue with the json produced since c# can't seem to parse it to the object.

Comment: You need to define the correct data types, as @RoarS. pointed out.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just did a test by setting is_successful to bool and the same error occurred.

Comment: Well, I'm not too familiar with C# so I can't really help here (which is why I commented on the PHP tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
Final solution was that there was a `json_encode` too much.

On the line before `var res = client.Execute(request);`, add this:

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
```

This is working:

```
var json = @"[{""original_file_name"":""Plain_HAIR.pdf"",""encrypted_file_name"":""UTTSJG13V1EC46J.pdf"",""is_successful"":true,""message"":"""",""email"":""[\""testuser@gmail.com\""]"",""doctype"":""HAIR""}]";
var convertedInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileUploadResultViewModel>>(json);
```

And surrounding with `"` is also working

```
var json2 = @"""[{""original_file_name"":""Plain_HAIR.pdf"",""encrypted_file_name"":""UTTSJG13V1EC46J.pdf"",""is_successful"":true,""message"":"""",""email"":""[\""testuser@gmail.com\""]"",""doctype"":""HAIR""}]""";
var convertedInstance2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileUploadResultViewModel>>(json);
```

Comment: It works when testing with Postman for me too. It doesn't work when it comes into my local application.

Comment: @JianYA: How do you send this in JSON: `'email' => NULL` ? Test JSON doesn't seem to reflect this.

Comment: This was from another test. I have also tried removing all fields and leaving is_successful and the same error occurs. It seems like my local app has difficulty deserializing the json from the server.

Comment: So far the only thing that has been successful is returning a simple string

Comment: @JianYA: Can you show us all code for the method that contains `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileUploadResultViewModel>>(res.Content);` ? BR

Comment: @JianYA: Found the problem, please see top of my updated answer. BR

Comment: I tried that and the same error appears. I have found out that my server returns this "\"{\\\"is_successful\\\":true}\"" Is this correct? I have asked it to only return one item from the object at the moment. Seems like there are too many slashes.

Comment: I found out what was going on. $this->response already does json_encode! I have been doing double the work for no reason. My apologies.